# Is there a way to sync shopify customers carts with a mobile flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, shopify

I'm looking for a way to synchronize my customers' shopping carts (logged in) to our mobile application (Flutter/dart).

The expected sync is from the site TO the app, because we have some products that use a "configurator" on the site and that can not be accessible on the app. For the moment we put this configurator part in Webview or Launch URL but it makes the clients of the mobile application "go outside the app", just for this specific customizable product.

And if they come back to the app, the product won't be in their cart... it will only be in the cart of their mobile browser. And that's even if they are logged in to their account all the way.

I've tested cart persistence tools, but without success.

But for the moment I haven't found any help or related topic on the net.

If you have any idea or direction to recommend I would be very happy!
Thanks a lot.